# How to show that $\lnot p \to (p \to q)$

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

How can I show using formal logic that $\lnot p \to (p \to q)$?  I'm looking for hints towards a propositional calculus proof, and would not accept an answer consisting solely of truth tables.

Comment: If you desire a "propositional calculus proof", you have to specify the *calculus* you are using: Tableau, Natural Deduction, Hilbert-style (and in this case, what axioms...).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without knowing the details of the deduction system your class uses, I'll assume you can do proofs by assumption.  In that case, assume $\neg p$.  Then assume $p$.  Then for proof by contradiction assume $\neg q$.  Then you can show $p\land \neg p$ so that you have a contradiction, and then you can infer $q$.  Closing this proof by assumption out you get $p\rightarrow q$ at the end of a proof by assumption starting with $\neg p$.  So again close the proof by assumption and derive $\neg p \rightarrow (p \rightarrow q)$.

Answer (score 3):

We know that the inverse of $a \rightarrow b$ is $a \wedge \neg b$. Therefore if   $\neg p \rightarrow (p \rightarrow q)$ is not correct then we must have $ \neg p \wedge \neg (p \rightarrow q)$ which is $ \neg p \wedge p \wedge \neg q $, but this would be a contradiction as we can not have $p$ and $-p$ at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

First, prove the following equivalence:
$$
(A\to(B\to C)) \equiv ((A\land B)\to C).
$$
From this, you can see that your formula is equivalent to $(\neg p\land p)\to q$. The antecedent $(\neg p\land p)$ is a contradiction, and somehow in your deductive system you can show that a contradiction implies anything ($q$).